# ReactNative - Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: react-native

After I placed the following code snippet in my application, this warning started to appear.

```
export default function Detail({route, navigation}) {

const productTitle = route.params.productTitle;

// Header title
navigation.setOptions({
    headerTitle: productTitle,
})
```

This view is a component to show the details of the product.

I can't make this change to a component? Can I leave it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can. however, you can use it in useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
       headerTitle: productTitle,
    })
},[])
```